# Error while assigning XML attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xslt

My input XML is as below:

```
<MessageOutput Status="2">
    <Source>External</Source>
    <Error>Server not reachable</Error>
    <LineNo>0</LineNo>
</MessageOutput>
```

My requirement is to write XSLT and check if `<Error>` tag has value "Server not reachable" and if yes then change the `Status` attribute value to "3".

I wrote below code but getting error:

> "XSLT Error: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated
>   with an element type "Status"."

Please assist.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Des" select="'Server not reachable'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Err" select="MessageOutput/Error"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/MessageOutput">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$Des=$Err">
                <MessageOutput Status="3">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </MessageOutput>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <MessageOutput Status=<xsl:value-of select="@Status"/>>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </MessageOutput>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Des" select="'Server not reachable'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Err" select="MessageOutput/Error"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/MessageOutput">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$Des=$Err">
                <MessageOutput Status="3">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </MessageOutput>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <MessageResult Status="{@Status}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </MessageResult>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Done. Once again Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Or shortly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MessageOutput[Error='Server not reachable']/@Status">
    <xsl:attribute name="Status">3</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```